# how to get rid of response bad request 400 in HttpUrlConnection?

Tags: java, parse-platform, httpurlconnection

Hi I am writing one Java program for creating parse object using parse rest API.
I used below code uing HttpUrlConnection but every time i am getting bad request.
I researched many threads here but not getting any relevant solution so asking new question

```
String surl = "https://api.parse.com/1/classes/DrivingTestQuestion";
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    // 2. Open connection
    HttpURLConnection conn =null;
    try {
        URL url = new URL(surl);

        conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

        conn.setRequestMethod("POST");          
        conn.setDoOutput(true);     
        conn.setRequestProperty("X-Parse-Application-Id",
                "87A3v8ImR58torzhrizQwVd6AULIK1dUBxGKqCTf");
        conn.setRequestProperty("X-Parse-REST-API-Key",
                "1tjhBILLSvJE5iEytQ0WvzYf9ig0nQzmuwE2TbXy");
        conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=UTF-8");     
         conn.connect();

        OutputStream os = conn.getOutputStream();
        os.write(json.toString().getBytes("UTF-8"));
         os.close();

        int HttpResult = conn.getResponseCode();
        if (HttpResult == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    conn.getInputStream(), "utf-8"));
            String line = null;
            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line + "\n");
            }
            br.close();

            System.out.println("" + sb.toString());

        } else {
            System.out.println(conn.getResponseMessage());
        }
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        conn.disconnect();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
        conn.disconnect();
    }
```

and below is my json which is request body

```
{"QuestionNumber":21,"Answers":["Sí, porque es la manera más correcta de reglarlo.","No; debe hacerse con el vehículo inmovilizado en terreno plano yhorizontal.","Sí, siempre que circule lentamente."],"question":"¿Es correcto reglar el espejo retrovisor interior con el vehículo en marcha?","TestNumber":"2","TestTypeId":1}
```

I tried using postman rest client and getting response in that but in program getting bad request

Comment: Doesn't Parse offer a Java client library?

Comment: Don't use parse, they are shutting down... I don't know what kind of errors you would get from them.
Usually bad request means that your request are malformed and the server cannot parse it.

Comment: @RoiKatz i know parse is shutting down its service but for now this is the requirement

Comment: @Thilo no official java client library for parse api

Comment: What is your exact post request? (let's say - output with fiddler)

Comment: @RoiKatz solved it using httpclient also made one mistake their in parse TestNumber filed is integer and i am sending it as string may be thats the reason for error